# symfony2 - security issue with login check

Tags: php, symfony

i have issue with simplest authorisation in recent symfony2,

my security.yml :

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        # pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        pattern:  /login
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        form_login:
            check_path: check
            login_path: login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /index
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

and part of DefaultControler.php

```
    public function loginAction() {

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render('JimmyTestBundle:Default:login.html.twig', array(
        // last username entered by the user
        'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}

public function checkAction() 
{

}
```

I fallow cook book from symfony website, checkAction supposed to be interpret by firewall layer, but is probably not cos its trow something like this when i try to login.

> The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?
>   500 Internal Server Error - LogicException

My login.html.twig is also almost copy and pasted from the tutorials. Any advice?

Comment: It might be expecting a return object from your checkAction function in your controller. Have you tried deleting that if you're not using it right now?

Answer (score 0):

Your "secured_area" firewall is missing a security-provider to actually catch the request sent to the check_path. providers are configured under `security.providers` like this:

```
providers:
    your_provider_name: name_of_provider_service
```

right now... you only have one provider named "in_memory" which is a special provider provided by symfony.

add it to the "secured_area" firewall in order to be used to authenticate the credentials posted to the check_path route.

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/admin
        provider:   in_memory
```

... and remove the unnecessary "login" firewall from your configuration

```
login:
    # pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
    pattern:  /login
    security: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to mention your controller in routing.yml, in your case something like

```
_demo_secured:
    resource: "@JimmyTestBundle/DefaultController.php"
    type:     annotation
```